# Reverse for 'forum_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['forumpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'] How can I do to solve the problem?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I would like to link this function to the link in the base Templates, but I have this error, what solution could be found? Should I use the Reverse function?

my views

```py
    def forumPostList(request, pk):
        conversation = get_object_or_404(Conversation, pk=pk)
        form_response = PostModelForm()
        posts_conversation = Post.objects.filter(conversation=conversation)
        context = {"conversation": conversation,
                   "posts_conversation": posts_conversation,
                   "form_response": form_response
                   }
        return render(request, "account/forum_post.html", context)
```

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}



    {% block content %}

    <h1>Received messages:</h1>
        <hr>
        <br>
            {% for post in posts_conversation %}

                <h3>{{ conversation.title }}</h3>
                <p>Posts: {{ post.author_post.posts.count }}</p>
                 <p>Posts: {{ post.author_post.username }}</p>


            {% endfor %}


    {% endblock content %}
```

My base

```html
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'forum_post' %}">forum_post</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`forumPostList` view needs to get 'pk' as parameter in url. So for calling it with a link, your link should specify 'pk'.
So you can use url block like this:

```
{% url 'forum_post' conversation_pk %}
```

That `coversation_pk` should be specified somehow.

Comment: thanks for the contribution. I have tried, but the error remains.<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'forum_post' conversation_pk %}">forum_post</a>........: Reverse for 'forum_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['forumpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: You should set 'conversation_pk' and then use it in url.

Comment: I had set url:  path('forumpost/<int:pk>/', forumPostList, name="forum_post"):

Comment: No, I mean something like this:  
    {% with conversation_pk=1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'forum_post' conversation_pk %}">forum_post</a>
    {% endwith %}
Or passing 'conversation_pk' value in context of template.

Comment: Thank you very much Sajjad for your contribution.
I followed your advice and solved the problem.